# I am not getting exact output using array_diff

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a edited form in which I am fetching data based on application id.
Here exactly what I am doing is fetching old data(before save) from database and saving in a variable.

And after save I am fetching new data which is updated in database.

```
     $edit_app_id =$_POST['Application_ID'];
            //getting old data based on edit_app_id;
            $old_data = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT company,collaborateMS,ARM64_Board,collaboration_Details,special_requirements,Status,Application_Comments FROM wp3_AXC where Application_ID='$edit_app_id' ") ;
            print_r($old_data);
            $result = $wpdb->update($table_name, $item, array('id' => $item['id']));


            if ($result) {
                $message = __('Item was successfully updated', 'custom_table_example');
                $new_data = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT company,collaborateMS,ARM64_Board,collaboration_Details,special_requirements,Status,Application_Comments FROM wp3_AXC where Application_ID='$edit_app_id' ") ;
                print_r($new_data);
                //comparing  2 results(old_data vs new_data )
                $edit_result=array_diff($old_data,$new_data);
                print_r($edit_result);
```

Result:

```
$old_data : stdClass Object ( [company] => i [collaborateMS] => Join Estuary Development [ARM64_Board] => 2 [collaboration_Details] => i [special_requirements] => i [Status] => Pending [Application_Comments] => h ) 

$new_data : stdClass Object ( [company] => j [collaborateMS] => Estuary on new ARM64 Hardware [ARM64_Board] => 0 [collaboration_Details] => j [special_requirements] => j [Status] => Pending [Application_Comments] => j )
```

I am getting ouput as mentioned in the above result.

I need to compare both and get the changes.

I have used the array_diff can i use this.

can any one help me Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: array_diff is used between two arrays. You are using it between objects.

Comment: Thank you !!! I got my answer by converting object into  array.$edit_result=array_diff((array)$old_data,(array)$new_data);
     var_dump($edit_result);